# Take parameter of a method into custom action filter MVC3 asp

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, custom-attributes, action-filter

I've been working on an application that everytime you register, modify, cancel, delete ,etc... something, a notification has to be sent to a user(if it is configured) so i'm planning to do this by saving a unique identifier of the proccess on the database and then check if the notification is configured with an id, a proccess and the unique identifier and after all this send the notification.

To do this i had this in mind... this on the controller

```
   [NotificationFilter(id=10,proccess="Excecution") ]
   public Register(Entity entity,Guid uid){

   }
```

This on the ActionFilter class

```
public class NotificationFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public int id{ get; set; }
    public string proccess{ get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {

         dosomething(id,name,uid)
    }
}
```

but I want to know if there is a way to get the uid parameter of my **Register** action into the **OnActionExecuted** method.

Comment: Suggestion: you should move your code into an answer and mark it as such, so that people have an easier time finding what your solution was.

Comment: @paul thanks for your suggestion, I just did what you said and it's clear now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking Neel Bhatt answer.. I did something like this to make this work.

```
public class NotificationFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public int _id;
    public string _proccess;
    public Guid _uid; 

    public NotificationFilter(int id,string proccess)
    {
        _id= id;
        _proccess = proccess;
    }
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
         var val = filterContext.ActionParameters["uid"];

        _uid = (Guid)val;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
         var uid = _uid;

         dosomething(id,name,uid)
    }
}
```

This works for me, and hope could be helpfull to someone else.

Answer (score 1):

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
 var model = filterContext.ActionParameters.SingleOrDefault(ap => ap.Key == "uid").Value;


       if (model != null)
       {
          dosomething(id, name, uid)
       }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Neel Bhatt, that works fine on OnActionExecuting, but ActionExecutedContext does not have ActionParameters.